# OpenCL: working with doubles error

Tags: opencl

The error states: 
**error: can't enable all OpenCL extensions or unrecognized OpenCL extension

   #pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable**

System configuration:

- Windows 7 on 64 bit
- Notebook with ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5400 series
- Visual Studio 2010

Drivers installed:

- AMD-APP-SDK-v2.8-Windows-64
- amd_catalyst_13.5_mobility_beta3

How can i solve this problem because i need to use double type in the kernel?
The directive is declared in the first kernel line.

Comment: You can check the device supported extensions with clGetDeviceInfo(…, CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS,…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GPU doesn't support double precision. This is why the OpenCL runtime is reporting it cannot enable the `cl_khr_fp64` extension. If you really need double precision, try using the CPU as an OpenCL device instead and run your kernel on that.

Comment: I think you are right. Is there any website where i can check to see if another ati board supports double precision or not?

Comment: One place to find opencl support details for various cards is http://clbenchmark.com/. For example, this page for your device: http://clbenchmark.com/device-environment.jsp?config=12278593